# Syslog-ng missing logs when network is interrupted

Tags: networking, syslog, syslog-ng

I am using syslog-ng to retrieve logs from a file to another host which is in the same network with the sender.

My configuration looks like this:

```
source file_source {
  file("/var/log/messages" follow-freq(2));
};

destination remote_host {
  network("remote_ip"
    transport("tcp")
    port(514)
  );
};


log {
  source(file_source);
  destination(remote_host);
};
```

In normal cases it works perfectly, however the network is interrupted at some stages and this causes some logs to being missed. I tried to use tcp instead of udp but it didn't helped.

What is the good approach for having a reliable connection, forcing syslog-ng to keep track of arrived messages and retries new messages?

Thank you!

I tried to use TCP instead of UDP to mitigate the issue. But it didn't make any difference.